# GnuTV: Can't stream video over rtp/udp

Tags: udp, rtp, dvb

On the server I tried:

```
gnutv -out udp raspberrypi 1000 arte
```

and

```
gnutv -out rtp raspberrypi 1000 arte
```

But on the client I can't recieve the stream!

```
Playing udp://raspberrypi:1000.
STREAM_UDP, URL: udp://raspberrypi:1000
Failed to connect to server
udp_streaming_start failed
No stream found to handle url udp://raspberrypi:1000

Playing rtp://raspberrypi:1000.
STREAM_RTP, URL: rtp://raspberrypi:1000
Failed to connect to server
rtp_streaming_start failed
No stream found to handle url rtp://raspberrypi:1000
```

Comment: Use Wireshark to see if your server plays out the stream at all. That would be a first step to check if the problem is on the client or server side. Also, have you tried using the IP address of your raspberry instead of the hostname?

Comment: Did you solved your problem?!

Comment: No, sorry I gave it up. But the IP/hostname of the server is correct but I also couldn't find any data from server with wireshark :|

Answer (score 0):

Try to use rtp://localhost:1000 on the client.